# Anniversaries webpart using Azure AD

Tags: javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, azure

I've a custom webpart Anniversaries, which get data from list.
[image: Anniversaries webpart]
[image: List with data for webpart]

This is my service to get data from list:

```
public get(listName: string, startDate: Date, AnniversariesNumberOfItemsToDisplay: number): Promise<Person[]> {
    return sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle(listName)
      .select(Fields.Email, Fields.HireDate, Fields.FullName)
      .items.get()
      .then(listItems => {
        let rawData = new Array<any>();

        listItems.forEach((item: any) => {
          const hireDate = moment
            .utc(item[Fields.HireDate])
            .local()
            .toDate();
          let anniversaryDate = moment(hireDate).year(moment().year());
          if (anniversaryDate.isBefore(moment(), 'date')) {
            anniversaryDate = anniversaryDate.add(1, 'year');
          }

          const PersonItem = {
            email: item[Fields.Email],
            fullName: item[Fields.FullName],
            hireDate,
            anniversaryDate: anniversaryDate.toDate()
          };
          rawData.push(PersonItem);
        });
        return rawData;
      });
  }
```

But is it possible to take data for all users in Azure AD without using a list?

[image: Data in Azure AD]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible to get users from Azure AD.

You can use [PnPjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) to do so where you can get users using `@pnp/graph` package. Below are some helpful links

- Get All Users from Azure Ad - https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/users/#get-users-in-the-organization
- Using `PnPjs` in SPFx - https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/#using-pnpsp-spfi-factory-interface-in-spfx
- Sample SPFx web part which does use graph api - https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-graph-telephonedirectory

Comment: @Propool did you work for you?

Answer (score 0):

That's really cool! Any plans to possibly make your app publicly available, surprising no one else has created anything specifically for anniversaries.

Comment: This is not an answer of the question. Rather this question can be asked by comment section